# What is the best way to plot numerical Y axis, X axis Time series for a categorical variable in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn, bokeh

**My Data Frame is in below format**

```
Amount  Category    Transactiondatetime
9445    A16             22-04-2015 19:42
2000    A23             23-04-2015 16:29
1398    A16             02-05-2015 15:17
1995    A7              27-06-2015 13:51
2000    A23             07-08-2015 17:31
```

**Variable Description**

Assume `category` variable as some product categories sold on a website.
Category variable has around 15-20 categories. 
Some products were sold 20 times in a year, some were sold 50 and so on for different different amount.

The time series is spread across the year and the data has 6000000 rows.

**Aim of my task**

I am interested in viewing which category gets most amount during which part of the year. This can be a little messy as the data is huge and there will be some over lapping in the categories on a time series scale.

So what would be the best way to visualize this kind of data - it can be matplotlib, seaborn or bokeh or any other library.

Will appreciate example with code.

[image]

Comment: if I understood correctly, [`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) might be what you need. try `ax = sns.lineplot(x="Transactiondatetime", y="Amount", hue="Category", data=df)` if your dataframe is `df`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use a bar graph with amount on the y-axis and time on the x-axis?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('something.csv')
df['Transactiondatetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Transactiondatetime'], infer_datetime_format=True)

categories = list(set(df['Category'].tolist()))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bar_width = 2.0
for category in categories:
    cat_df = df[df['Category'] == category]
    times = cat_df['Transactiondatetime'].tolist()
    values = cat_df['Amount'].tolist()
    ax.bar(times, values, bar_width, label=category)

ax.legend()
plt.xlabel('Transaction Date')
plt.ylabel('Amount')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure about using bar chart as it has 15-20 categories with transactional data of 6000000 records span in 1 year. It will get really messy but I will try that. Can we plot stacked bars in time series ???

Comment: you can plot stacked bars, it will just make the comparison difficult. Have you tried this method and was it ugly? If you try this and post the output graph, I can give some feedback on how to make it better. Since I don't have your dataset I am not sure what would be the best to do without seeing it

Comment: I tried to create bar chart using your code but it was taking a very long time to run so I cancelled that. 

Then I created the plot with sns.lineplot. I have added the actual data plot image to the post now. If you think bar chart can improve the visibility in the plot then I will try it again.